# Accessing Google's speech recognition service

Tags: speech-recognition

In most of the Android phones there is an option to dictate the text rather than typing it. Is it possible to access this service separately using a url? For example, I sent the recorded speech to this service and it then gives me the text output. Is it possible? Could you please let me know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an unofficial Google Speech API that was reversed engineered and posted on [this blog](http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/).  This article shows how to access it using Perl, but it gives you enough direction to figure out how to do it in another language. The problem with using an unofficial API is that it can change without notice and there is no support or documentation.

Nuance has a [mobile SDK for speech recognition](http://www.nuance.com/for-developers/dragon-mobile-sdk/index.htm). I think there is a web service under the hood of this SDK. I know that Nuance purchased a cloud based speech recognition service but it was not clear to me how they incorporated it into their product line.

Another commercially available service is [Nexiwave](http://nexiwave.com/). There use to be a service provided by YapMe, but it looks like it is no longer available.

Comment: I just found and open source tool called Sphinx which does voice recognition? Is that a good solution? Could you please suggest?

Comment: Sphinx has been around for a while and I have heard good things about it although I have heard it can be hard to setup and configure. You can search StackOverflow for answers to some questions on Sphinx, such as how to install PocketSphinx on an Android. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020291/installing-pocketsphinx-on-android/4750312#4750312]

Comment: YapMe was acquired by Amazon. I have no idea what they are doing with it, but I hope they expose it as a web service as part of AWS - http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2011/11/i-see-your-siri-and-raise-you-a-yap-amazon-quietly-snaps-up-speech-recognition-startup/248165/

Comment: Here is an older SO answer that attempted to survey a bunch of common solutions. It may be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6351055/90236